# Discord API: Providing messages from incorrect time period

Tags: python, api, http, discord.py

Im trying to get all messages from a channel from 2 days ago till now. instead, it's giving me the messages from the inception of the channel. Don't know what I'm doing wrong here...

here is the code

```
import requests
import json
import datetime

def retrieve_messages(channelid, after=None, before=None):
    headers = {
        'authorization': "<TOKEN>"
    }

    # Build the query string, including the after and before parameters
    # if they were specified
    query_string = '?'
    if after:
        query_string += f'&after={after}'
    if before:
        query_string += f'&before={before}'

    # Make the API call, including the query string
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages{query_string}', headers=headers)
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in jsonn:
        print(value['content'], '\n')

# Retrieve messages from the past two days
two_days_ago = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
after = int(two_days_ago.timestamp())
retrieve_messages("<CHANNEL_ID>", after=after)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. It is in the documentation

```
# Define the DISCORD_EPOCH constant
DISCORD_EPOCH = 1420070400000

# Convert the x_days_ago variable to a timestamp in milliseconds
timestamp_ms = int(x_days_ago.timestamp() * 1000)

# Subtract the DISCORD_EPOCH constant from the timestamp to get the correct format for the after parameter
after = (timestamp_ms - DISCORD_EPOCH) << 22
```

Answer (score 0):

The discord.py API uses timestamps in milliseconds, not seconds. So:

```py
# ...
if after:
    query_string += f'&after={after * 1000}'  # Multiply by 1000 (convert to ms)
if before:
    query_string += f'&before={before}'
```